# Rowsums isn't adding correctly?

Tags: r

I have a presence absence database with a bunch of zeroes and ones, but when i use rowsums, it seems to only count a portion of the data and then stop. Here's my code

```
site_matrix=read.csv("TriassicMatrix1.csv", header=T) # create object called site_matrix
summary(site_matrix) # get summary
head(site_matrix) # check out first few columns
tail(site_matrix) # check out last few columns
View(site_matrix) # take a look at whole dataset in new window

# here's the problematic line 

spp_rich=rowSums(site_matrix [,2:25]) # generate richness for sites
```

There are 25 rows of data, and it gives me incorrect output, such as suggesting the first row only has 4 occurances when it has 7.

I tried changing it to [,1,25]  and it won't work since row 1 is my title row, so I know it's not that. When I view the data within R i can very easily go to row 2 and count out the data, since there is only a few hundred columns.

It appears to be 'cutting off' at about the halfway point, column-wise.

Comment: Please double check what you want to sum - when using `site_matrix[, X:Y]` you're subsetting columns and using all rows. Also, if first row in your matrix is title row - then you  matrix might be invalid as all values in it are characters.

Comment: If you want to sum by row for rows 2 to 25 and _all_ columns, your subsetting should look like `site_matrix[2:25,]` (first entry in square brackets refers to rows and second to columns, leaving it empty means use all columns). If your goal is to just skip the first row, `site_matrix [-1,]` will also do (`-1` means use all rows except for the first one)